# Querying inside Parse.Cloud.beforeSave

Tags: parse-platform

Here is what I am trying to do

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Users", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var user = request.object;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("installationId", user.get("installationId"));
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
    if(results !== undefined ) {
        console.log("beforeSave Users:" + results + " User Exists For :" +user.get("installationId"));  
        response.error();
        }
    else{
        console.log("beforeSave Users:" + results + " Creating User For :" +user.get("installationId"));
        response.success();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // on error, log it and return an empty array
        console.log("beforeSave Users Error :" + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

It works fine but I get this in result

I2014-06-30T01:51:02.578Z] v99: before_save triggered for Users
  Input: {"original":null,"update":{"installationId":"ef0317be-e634-4f64-a482-810c9839117c","userName":"Test","userPhoneNumber":"0123456789"}}
  **Result: Validation failed**

Why this validation failed is there? If I remove `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` then this validation error goes away but my function stops working.

Can someone explain please? Why is this validation failed error?

Even if results are not found and I get an empty array, I want a successful results. The problem is I am trying to understand that how adding or removing `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` makes a difference in this case.

It makes my code work but why I do get result: Validation failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic in your `success` handler is incorrect.

If no matches were found, the `results` parameter will be an empty array. You should be checking for a length of 0.

Given that you're only expecting a single result though, you should probably switch to using `first()` instead, in which case you would want to check for `undefined`.